# Is my double disk failure stochastic or indicates a systemic issue?

Tags: raid, hard-drive

I'm running a home server on an aging [N54L Proliant Microserver](https://n40l.fandom.com/wiki/Base_Hardware_N54L). 6 months ago, it had the following disks:

- sda SanDisk_SDSSDP064G (64G SSD) (boot)
- sdb WDC_WD30EZRX (WDC Green 3TB HDD) (RAID-1)
- sdc WDC_WD30EZRX (WDC Green 3TB HDD) (RAID-1)
- sdd WDC_WD80PURZ (WDC Purple 8TB HDD)
- sde WDC_WD30EZRX (WDC Green 3TB HDD)

The server was running Ubuntu 18.04 and the non-boot disks were managed with ZFS. `sdb`/`sdc` held the most important stuff and were mirrored. `sdd` and `sde` held less important stuff. I also have a cold 14TB USB drive to which I occasionally copy everything. Finally, I'd occasionally snapshot the most-most important stuff and zfs send to `sde` and Cloud (GCP GCS Nearline storage).

The Green 3TB drives are 9 years old (!), and survived several house moves. The Purple 8TB is 3.5 years old. Now, about 6 months ago I started getting read errors on `sde`. Since it only had not-so-important data and was mainly where I snapshotted the RAID-1, it didn't really bother me. I figured I'd fix it when I get to it. Last weekend I had some spare time, got a new TOSHIBA_HDWD130 (3TB) from Amazon, upgraded the server to Ubuntu 20.04 and replaced the bad `sde`.

Now the problem: as I was copying data over, I started getting read errors on `sdb`. :-/ I used `zpool replace` to add the new Toshiba into the mirror and take out the 2nd failing WDC, but now I'm thinking what to do next.

Should I simply replace the 2nd failing disk and go my merry way, or replace the whole array/server for fear of something worse (power, backplane, heat, ...)? What should I take into account when making the decision?

(NB: while asking the question I came up with a conclusion I'm willing to go with and will shortly answer my own question; would love for others to review my work and decision)

Answer (score -1):

Only replace the failing disk, everything else is fine.

Looking at [Google's](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/disk_failures.pdf) and [Backblaze's](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/backblaze-hard-drive-stats-q1-2020/) figures, we can reasonably expect an AFR of 6% for these elderly drives. That would make my double failure have roughly a 2% probability if the events are truly uncorrelated. Of course the events are more correlated than that: even in a healthy server disks share some fate, vibrations, heat, etc.

So actually this "double disk failure" wasn't "likely", but wasn't "omg lolz wtf". Given that I still have plenty of redundancy with the cold+cloud backup, given this is a home project (in terms of budget and data criticality), and given that I can reasonably expect that ZFS will continue saving me from silent corruption, I'll only replace this one bad disk.

I didn't do a proper risk cost analysis, but off the cuff I'd say that I'd pay $250 to bring back the not-so important data, $500 to bring back the important data, and an unknown sum but probably more than $5K to bring back the most-most important data (wedding pictures, my kids baby pics etc). I think deciding how much would I pay to un-lose this data is necessary to make the decision, and even though I didn't do the maths (which [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Failure-Risk-Management-Why-Broken/dp/0470387955) explains well I think), I think the sums here are in line with my investment and backup strategy.